# Access to custom property in extended MatPaginatorIntl class

Tags: angular, typescript

Code that I'm testing is here:
[Test code - Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vqbvpq-yac6ec?file=app/paginator-configurable-example.ts)

I'm using an extended MatPaginatorIntl class to customize its labels.
It works, but I would like to set a custom variable (called someProperty in this code example):

```
import { MatPaginatorIntl } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CustomMatPaginatorIntl extends MatPaginatorIntl {
    public someProperty: number;
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.getAndInitTranslations();
    }
    
    setSomeProperty(value:number)
    {
        this.someProperty = value;
    }

    getAndInitTranslations() {

        this.itemsPerPageLabel = "Items per page";
        this.nextPageLabel = "Next";
        this.previousPageLabel = "Previous";
        this.changes.next();
    }
    override getRangeLabel = (page: number, pageSize: number, length: number) => {
        return `${this.someProperty}`; // use someProperty here
    }
}
```

In the paginator-configurable-example.ts, I would like to set that variable (e.g. in OnInit), but the following approach is not working (sorry if it is completely wrong):

```
export class PaginatorConfigurableExample implements OnInit{
  @ViewChild(MatPaginatorIntl) pag: MatPaginatorIntl;
  // MatPaginator Inputs
  length = 100;
  pageSize = 10;
  pageSizeOptions: number[] = [5, 10, 25, 100];

  // MatPaginator Output
  pageEvent: PageEvent;

  setPageSizeOptions(setPageSizeOptionsInput: string) {
    this.pageSizeOptions = setPageSizeOptionsInput.split(',').map(str => +str);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // SET MatPaginatorIntl variable
    this.pag.setSomeProperty(100);
  }
}
```

How could I access the custom variable from the PaginatorConfigurableExample code?

Comment: `@ViewChild(MatPaginatorIntl) pag: MatPaginatorIntl;` should be `@ViewChild(CustomMatPaginatorIntl ) pag: CustomMatPaginatorIntl ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ViewChild` works only for classes that are decorated with `@Component` / `@Directive` [Angular ViewChild Documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description)

So here is the solution:

1. Add @Directive decorator to `CustomMatPaginatorIntl` instead of @Injectable.

```
    @Directive({ selector: 'mat-paginator' })
    export class CustomMatPaginatorIntl extends MatPaginatorIntl {
        ...
    }
```

2. In `main.ts`; remove `CustomMatPaginatorIntl` from `providers` and add it to `declarations`.

```
  declarations: [CustomMatPaginatorIntl, PaginatorConfigurableExample],
```

3. In the `paginator-configurable-example.ts`, change the `ViewChild` type from `MatPaginatorIntl` to `CustomMatPaginatorIntl`

```
@ViewChild(CustomMatPaginatorIntl) pag: CustomMatPaginatorIntl;
```

Forked working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vqbvpq-lj8xmi?file=app/paginator-configurable-example.ts

[image: console.log after setting some property]